# Google map original marker image overlapping selected marker

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, location, google-maps-markers

Here, I have uploaded an image of my problem where you can check my selected marker is overlapped by the original marker. I don't know the reason. Here is my code for selecting a marker

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

            //Here I am checking that selected marker is not my current location marker
            if marker != currentLocationMarker{

                if let selectedMarker = mapView.selectedMarker {
                    selectedMarker.icon = UIImage(named : "scooterPin")
                }

                mapView.selectedMarker = marker
                selectedScooterLocation = CLLocation(latitude: marker.position.latitude, longitude: marker.position.longitude)
                marker.icon = UIImage(named : "selectedScooterPin")

                currentLocationMarker.icon = UIImage(named : "currentLocationMarker")

                mapView.animate(to: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: marker.position.latitude, longitude: marker.position.longitude, zoom: mapView.camera.zoom))

            }

            return true
    }
```

[image: Overlapping marker image]

Comment: @SahilManchanda These are dummy data

Comment: You don't need `mapView.selectedMarker = marker`

Comment: @RajeshKumarR checking

Comment: @RajeshKumarR Not working, Now all markers selected one by one